# jQuery on blackberry simulator

Tags: jquery, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

We have a simple mobile web application using jQuery.

The application is working good on a real blackberry 9700 device. But it's not working on 9700 simulator.

Any suggestions on solving this problem are appreciated.

-Chaitanya

Comment: It would help if you provide more details, like, what is not working, do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the actual device is the latest version of blackberry 9700 series. So, it could have some patches or updates. But on the simulator we could not get it to work.

Also, since blackberry 5.0 has very limited support to javascript and css, we could not get jQuery to work effectively.

Hence, we dropped out using jQuery and using XUI JS library for blackberry.

Comment: XUI is pretty much jQuery for mobile, whereas JQuery Mobile is like JQuery UI.